# Azure B2C Graph API issue

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to run the sample at:

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-dotnetcore-b2c-account-management

And am receiving this error:

Enter command, then press ENTER: 7
Create a user with the custom attributes 'FavouriteSeason' (string) and 'LovesPets' (boolean)
Have you created the custom attributes 'FavouriteSeason' (string) and 'LovesPets' (boolean) in your tenant?

Code: Request_BadRequest
Message: One or more property values specified are invalid.
Inner error:
AdditionalData:
date: 2020-06-30T23:24:26
request-id: dad23cee-984b-439c-a943-9e1bc6be4c9b
ClientRequestId: dad23cee-984b-439c-a943-9e1bc6be4c9b

I have created the custom attributes and can clear see them in the tenant...it even returns their ids.  I've setup the Graph access level appropriately (I believe).

Any ideas?  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

1. In Code, you need to update Tenant id, client id, client secret and also give B2cExtensionAppClientId= “your application display name” in appsettings.json
2. You have to create two custom attributes in the B2C portal

   I.  FavouriteSeason (string)

   II. LovesPets (boolean)
3. Use below code to create the user with the custom attribute

   ```
            try
            {
                //Create user
                var result = await graphClient.Users
                .Request()
                .AddAsync(new User
                {
                    GivenName = "Casey",
                    Surname = "Jensen",
                    DisplayName = "Casey Jensen",
                    Identities = new List<ObjectIdentity>
                    {
                        new ObjectIdentity()
                        {
                            SignInType = "emailAddress",
                            Issuer ="AADCxPb2c.onmicrosoft.com",


                            IssuerAssignedId = "x@AADCxPb2c.onmicrosoft.com",
                        }
                    },
                    PasswordProfile = new PasswordProfile()
                    {
                        Password = b2c_ms_graph.Helpers.PasswordHelper.GenerateNewPassword(4, 8, 4)
                    },
                    PasswordPolicies = "DisablePasswordExpiration",
                    AdditionalData = extensionInstance


                }) ;
                Console.WriteLine(result);
                string userId = result.Id;
                Console.WriteLine(result.Id);
                Console.WriteLine($"Created the new user. Now get the created user with object ID '{userId}'...");
   ```

Comment: Still not working...the following calls work:

[1]      Get all users (one page)
[2]      Get user by object ID
[3]      Get user by sign-in name
[8]      Get all users (one page) with custom attributes

The other calls:
[4]      Delete user by object ID (not tried)
[5]      Update user password (Getting a permission error)
[6]      Create users (bulk import) (not tried)
[7]      Create user with custom attributes and show result (error in original post above)

Comment: Please use this Powrershell  command  New-AzureADApplicationExtensionProperty -ObjectId <> -Name "FavouriteSeason" -DataType "String" -TargetObjects "User"

Comment: Please let us know if this answer was helpful to you. If so, please remember to mark it as the answer using the check mark so that others in the community with similar questions can more easily find a solution. Also, Please spare few mins to let us know how we did using this link <https://microsoft.qualtrics.com/jfe/form/SV_6Sh1E5ZBWke4wO9?Q_DL=Fa5t8dkcKtAi0la_6Sh1E5ZBWke4wO9_MLRP_3V5ZY3Iya7w0DQx&Q_CHL=gl>

Answer (score 0):

Can find it on your registered App on Azure AD B2C:

1. Click on "API Permissions" on left panel.
2. Then Chose "APIs my organization uses".
3. You can find the value under name "b2c-extensions-app. Do not modify. Used by AADB2C for storing user data.".